# Cakephp 1.3 appfog database configuration

Tags: php, cakephp, migration, database-connection, cakephp-1.3

i just moving my blog to appfog. I am currently using cakephp 1.3.x. I know I need to upgrade, I am already working on it. But in the meantime, I would like to get my blog working. I am not able to configure the database file.

I know we need to add

```
$services_json = json_decode(getenv('VCAP_SERVICES'),true);
$af_mysql_config = $services_json['mysql-5.1'][0]['credentials'];
// Database settings
Configure::write('Database.config', array(
    'default' => array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => $af_mysql_config['hostname'],
        'login' => $af_mysql_config['username'],
        'password' => $af_mysql_config['password'],
        'database' => $af_mysql_config['name'],
        'prefix' => '',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
    )
));
```

I just want to know how we can send the setting to database config.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you saying you can't edit `APP/config/database.php`? I don't *think* you can do this, as Cake uses a specific `DATABASE_CONFIG` class, rather than `Configure::`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did this:

class DATABASE_CONFIG {

```
public $default = null;
function __construct() {

    $services = getenv("VCAP_SERVICES");
    $services_json = json_decode($services, true);
    $mysql_config = $services_json["mysql-5.1"][0]["credentials"];

    $this->default = array(
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => $mysql_config["hostname"],
        'login' => $mysql_config["user"],
        'password' => $mysql_config["password"],
        'database' => $mysql_config["name"],
        'prefix' => '',
        'port' => $mysql_config["port"],
    );
}
```

}